# What SQL argument have I got wrong?

Tags: sql, command-prompt, restore

Background: I have both SQL2008 and SQL2012 installed on my machine. This has resulted in only having the studio management for 2012 running, and any amount of trying wont let me add the studio for 2008.

Problem: Now I have backup that for verification reasons need to be restored on the 2008 instance without the 2012 management studio to avoid contamination, so I am trying to run the restore directly from the command prompt. I have let the 2012 studio make the actual command for me, and am now trying to put that into the prompt, but it won't run; and no amount of reading makes me see the invalid argument. I realize I am probably missing something elemental, but please have a look at it anyway.

The command that I am trying to run is:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn>SqlCmd -E -S SQL2008 "RESTORE DATABASE Basename FROM  DISK = N'D:\Folder\Backup.BAK' WITH  FILE = 1,  MOVE N'Base_Data' TO N'C:\Folder\Base.mdf',  MOVE N'Base_1_Data' TO N'C:\Folder\Base_1.ndf',  MOVE N'Base_2_Data' TO N'C:\Folder\Base_2.ndf',  MOVE N'Base_Log' TO N'C:\Folder\Base_3.LDF',  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5"
```

And the response is a quick: Unexpected argument. Enter '-?' for help.

I don't see how -E or -S could be wrong, and the server is correct 2008 instance. I have tried it without the MOVEs to see if there could be something there, but it gave the same result.

So could someone please swing a 2 by 4 my way letting me know what I am doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: Restoring from 2012 studio works fine, so there is something in the arguments that I am missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe like this?

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn>SqlCmd -E -S SQL2008 -Q "RESTORE DATABASE Basename FROM  DISK = N'D:\Folder\Backup.BAK' WITH  FILE = 1,  MOVE N'Base_Data' TO N'C:\Folder\Base.mdf',  MOVE N'Base_1_Data' TO N'C:\Folder\Base_1.ndf',  MOVE N'Base_2_Data' TO N'C:\Folder\Base_2.ndf',  MOVE N'Base_Log' TO N'C:\Folder\Base_3.LDF',  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5"
```

Comment: Same result: Unexpected argument. Enter '-?' for help.
:(

Comment: Turns out there was some sort of formatting error when pasting the argument into the command line window... Wanted to try it in a window without administrator rights, and copied it into notepad, reformatted to get the linebreaks, and suddenly it ran !?!?!

I have no idea where the incorrect character/break was, as it doesn't show up anywhere

Comment: @Svend unfortunately it's more common than you'd think.  In particular, Word, Wordpad, Outlook and a bunch of other tools and products have the nasty habit changing normal quotes and apostrophes into "articulated" quotes, which look fancy, but are invalid to most language comiplers, including both DOS and T-SQl.

Comment: My dash (–) was a "en dash" (character hex 2013) and sqlcmd want a "hyphen-minus" (-).  Subtle ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the most common issue with this problem is copying and pasting from some other source, as mentioned in the comments in the other answer. My problem was copying and pasting from this article:

http://www.howtogeek.com/50295/backup-your-sql-server-database-from-the-command-line/

To fix this, try typing your command in manually so you know the exact value of every character. Usually the problem characters are double quotes, but they can also be single quotes, and my problem was in fact the dash character being U-2014, the "EN DASH". Even the spaces could potentially be nonblocking spaces i suppose.